About the definition of cDV singularity
M. Reid defines cDV singularity as follow in his paper "CANONICAL 3-FOLDS"
A point $p\in X$ of a 3-fold is called a compound Du Val point if for some section H throgh $P$, $P\in H$ is a Du val singularity.
Equivalently, $P\in X$ is cDV singularity if it is locally analytically isomorphic to the hypersurface singularity given by $f+tg$ where $f\in k[x,y,z]$ is a polynomial defining Du Val singularity and $g\in k[x,y,z,t]$ is arbitrary.
But why these  two definitions equivalent.
Especially why does the latter condition imply the former one?
Can we say something about sections passing through $P$ from analytic (formal) property?
Is section $t=0$ algebraic?
